# Can I use those Plasma KDE desktop effects on gnome shell?

Tags: gnome, kde, gnome-shell, plasma

I have noticed that there is a collection of beautiful desktop effects that can be used in KDE Plasma. I used them on Plasma. But I like to use those beautiful effects on gnome too. Specially that 'Magic Lamp' effect. Is it possible? If so can any one give a piece of information about how to achieve that?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to import KDE effects into Gnome. You can hunt around and find some Gnome effects that are similar but KDE is KDE.

Comment: @Dinil interesting question, but I see it's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of those effects you enjoy from KWin are available in other compositing engines. However, because Gnome based Ubuntu systems have been making drastic changes to their compositors for the last few years that forks into two answers:

## 16.04 with Unity/Compiz

The default compositor for versions up until 16.04 was Compiz. You can try using them by installing the Compiz Config Settings Manager and extra plugins:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-main compiz-plugins-extra
```

There is a plugin there called Magic Lamp which is almost identical to the KWin one in appearance.

## 18.04 with Gnome 3/Mutter

Starting with Ubuntu 18.04 Unity was replaced with Gnome 3 which uses the Mutter compositor. Mutter by design does not have much configurability or plugins. It's possible you may be able to configure Compiz to run with 18.04 and keep Gnome 3, I am not sure. See this question for more info on that:

[Is there a settings manager available for Mutter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80578/is-there-a-settings-manager-available-for-mutter)